# What is the scope of using namespace in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, using-directives

When specifying `using namespace` within PowerShell module or script file, is there a scope associated with the directive into which namespace symbols are being introduced?

Or are namespace symbols introduced into global session state avoiding the PS scope modifiers?

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation.Runspaces
```

For example if we specify `using namespace` inside module it would be great if this applies to module scope only.

Likewise if we specify `using namespace` inside script file it would be great if this applies to that script only unless dot sourced.

I didn't test any of this and was not able to find documentation regarding this question.

Comment: `using ...` statements are already script-scoped - they apply to the scope they're defined in. Test it and you'll see :)

Comment: I did test it and indeed it's either module scope or script scope as long as script file isn't dot sourced.

Comment: I also found an issue related to this question: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13768

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `using namespace` statement follows PowerShell's usual dynamic scoping rules<sup>[1]</sup>:

- It takes effect in the scope in which it is placed *and all descendant scopes*.

  - If a script file (`*.ps1`) is [dot-sourced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-)  (e.g. `. ./file.ps1`), the statement takes effect in the *caller's* scope.
- Since modules have their own scope domains ("session states") that are connected only to the *global* scope, a `using namespace` statement in a module doesn't affect any module-external callers.

  - **Caveat**: As of PowerShell 7.1, you cannot use name-only type literals that rely on `using namespace` statements (e.g., `[Command]` for [`[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command)) *in  `[OutputType([...])]` attributes of exported functions* (they work fine in parameter declarations and function bodies), as detailed in the GitHub issue you've discovered, [GitHub issue #13768](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13768).

---

<sup>[1] As of this writing, the conceptual [about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes) help topic doesn't *explicitly* discuss the *dynamic* nature of PowerShell's scoping as such (as distinct from the *lexical* scoping you would find in languages such as C#). In simple terms, PowerShell's dynamic scoping means that, inside a given scope domain (non-module code vs. a given module's code), code called from a given caller is affected by the *runtime* state of that caller, such as by `using` statements, `Set-StrictMode` settings, and the visibility of the caller's variables.</sup>